# Struct errors with C++?

Tags: c++, struct

so I am reading C++primer 6th edition and am up to structs, but when trying to make a test file to run I get the following error:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~/C/C$ make test
g++     test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
make: *** [test] Error 1
xubuntu@xubuntu:~/C/C$
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
        char name[20];
        float age;
        float worth;
};

int main(){
        using namespace std;
        test chris = {"Chris", 22, 22};
        cout << "This is Chris's data:" << test.chris;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not in an external link.

Comment: test.chris does not exist. test is the name of structure; chris is the instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout << "This is Chris's data:" << test.chris` this is wrong.

It should be `cout << "This is Chris's data:" << chris.name`

Answer (score 3):

You may try doing it like this:-

```
cout << "This is Chris's name:" << chris.name;
```

`test` is the name of the struct and `chris` is the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is the name of the struct, `chris` is the name of the variable, so you need to be referring to `chris`. And you'll need to reference each field individually to print it out. IE:

```
cout << "This is Chris's name:" << chris.name;
cout << "This is Chris's age:" << chris.age;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is clearly written : test.cpp:14:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

replace

```
cout << "This is Chris's data:" << test.chris;
```

with

```
    cout << "This is Chris's data:" << chris.name << " " << chris.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `test.chris`.

`chris` is the name of your struct variable.

What you want to call is `chris.name`.

Comment: "What you want to call is test.name" Should it not be more chris.name ?

Comment: test is the name of the struct.  chris is the variable name.  So it will be `chris.name`, not `test.name`.

Comment: Sorry yes, got them mixed up

Answer (score 0):

That's because `test.chris` doesn't exist.

You want to use the `chris.name`, `chris.worth`, `chris.age` directly.

If you want to use something like `std::cout << chris` you have to overload the `<<` operator. For example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const test &theTest) {
     stream << "Name: " << theTest.name << ", Worth: " << theTest.worth << ", Age: " << theTest.age;
     return stream;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
    test chris = {"Chris", 22, 22};
    cout << "This is Chris's data:" << chris;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has yet mentioned it, if you still want to use

```
cout << "This is Chris's data:" << // TODO
```

consider overloading the output stream operator "<<". This will tell the compiler what to do when it encounters a test object as the right-operand of the output stream operator.

```
struct test{
    char name[20];
    float age;
    float worth;
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const test &);       // prototype

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const test & t){ // implementation
    // Format the output however you like
    out << " " << t.name << " " << t.age << " " << t.worth;
    return out;
}
```

so that this line now works:

```
cout << "This is Chris's data:" << chris;
```

Answer (score -1):

`test.chris` does not exist.  If you want to output the whole struct, you need to do something like:

```
std::cout << "This is Chris's Data:  " << chris.name << ", " << chris.age << ", " << chris.worth << std::endl;
```